# How does sorting works in Java with reference to Comparable and Comparator?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator, comparable

I have a class Employee implementing Comparable interface

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {

        private int id;
        private String name;
        private int age;
        private long salary;

        public Employee(int id, String name, int age, int salary) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.salary = salary;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Employee emp) {
        return (this.id - emp.id);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
        return "[id=" + this.id + ", name=" + this.name + ", age=" + this.age + ", salary=" +
            this.salary + "]";
        }

}
```

I have a `Employee[]` array I am sorting the array using `Arrays.sort()`

```
Employee[] empArr = new Employee[4];
empArr[0] = new Employee(10, "Mikey", 25, 10000);
empArr[1] = new Employee(20, "Arun", 29, 20000);
empArr[2] = new Employee(5, "Lisa", 35, 5000);
empArr[3] = new Employee(1, "Pankaj", 32, 50000);

Arrays.sort(empArr);
```

My question is how is sorting working internally,
is it like `emArr[0].compareTo(emArr[1])` then swap the element if required?

I want to know how comparison and swapping are happening inside? and what role does `Comparatable's compareTo(Object o)` and `Comparator's compare(o1,o2)` are playing ?

Comment: Search on google you will find lots of example that how sorting is working in this case.

Comment: Different sorting algorithms sort differently, of course. Read about SelectionSort, Quicksort, MergeSort, etc

Comment: I did search a lot

Comment: @ControlAltDel I am very comfortable with sorting algos, just want to know the JAVA API's internal details.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source code of `Arrays.sort()` yourself?

Comment: You need to override `equals` and `hashCode` still. As you show it, `compareTo` is inconsistent with them.

Comment: Java makes no promises about the internal workings of the sort algorithm. It guarantees externally visible behavior - for example, the sort must be stable - and the docs do make a few notes about how the official JDK's current algorithm works, but it doesn't promise that future implementations will work the same, and it doesn't require alternative implementations to work the same.

Comment: @AndyThomas Did read it. It is calling some `mergeSort()` if array is small they are using `insertion sort` otherwise `mergesort` but I am not getting complicated few thing eg. `    ((Comparable) dest[j-1]).compareTo(dest[j])>0; j--)`

Comment: @user2357112 sir that's if fine. But I wan't to what magic is happening because of `Comparator` and `Comparable`

Comment: @piechuckerr: Comparator and Comparable just let the sort know what elements should be considered "greater". They're basically how you define your own `>` and `<`. There's nothing special going on there.

Comment: @user2357112 Okay got it. Would be nice if you write it in answer section with some details, so that I can give you the deserved credits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are already Sorting techniques for arranging any collection of items in an order. Java utility classes like Arrays, Collections use these techniques. 
For any such sorting technique to work it is important to define how to decide which of the two objects are greater.

This information is provided in the implementation of `compareTo()` in case of the Object's class implements `Comparable` interface.

This information can also be provided in the implementation of `compare()` method of the `Comparator` class. Comparator class is useful in case you want to define different ordering  as per the requirement (may be based on some parameter during run time). It may be possible that the class of the entity implements Comparable interface but we want for some specific case the sorting to be of different order or based on some other parameter.

Read more on `Comparable` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

and `Comparator` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Answer (score 0):

`Comparable` implies a natural ordering. Generally speaking if `A.compareTo(B) == 0` then `A.equals(B) == true` (this is a general convention that isn't always followed).

`Comparator` is utilized when you want to sort by something other than natural order. For example you want to order an array of integers so that all even numbers appear first.

`Arrays.sort()` is using a merge sort. See the [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[])) API for details.